# value from span to input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have value that is displayed in span tag. If i want to post the value i have to assign that value to an input. So this is the code i have written to assign value to input and trying to post that value. But when i alert the assigned value its 
showing as

```
[object Object]
```

Pls check the code and correct me.

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower);
```

and i tried this also

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower);
```

Both the above code shows

```
[object Object]
```

Because of this i am not able to post values.

Comment: you can use console.log to check object instead of alert

Comment: Obviously, its object which is stored in `lower`.. `Console.log(lower)` to see in detail..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the value setter function on an input return the jQuery object of that input element only, it allows you to chain the event.

Try this

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
```

Read more about it here [**http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value**](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)

Answer (score 2):

"lower" is an object. if you want to see the text inside, you need to call lower.val().
e.g.

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports chaining objects return.

So, whenever you do an operation on an object (except some like `.val()` getter, it returns object of that selector element.

So, you can do much more operations in a single statement.

In your statement,

```
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower);,
```

It is returning the object of element `#lower`.

You can add more operations to it.

For example:

```
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value).css('color', 'red');
```

You want only plain value.

So, rather you should do this:

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
$("#inputElement").val(value);
var lower=$("#inputElement").val();
alert(lower);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do in this way..

```
var span_text = $("#spanElement").text(); //get span text
$("#inputElement").val(span_text); //set span text to input value
var input_value = $("#inputElement").val(); //get input value
alert(input_value); //alert input value
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

This is because it will return a jQuery object . If you want to see the same text which is in the input you can either use `.val()` like answered previously or use like this

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert($("#spanElement").prop('innerHTML'));
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vpzovbhh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 'Object Object' because lower is an object if you want to get the text you need to perform below actions.

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
```

Or

```
var value = $("#spanElement").text();
var lower=$("#inputElement").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
```

Hope it helps !