# Manipulate value dynamically (onchange) from span to input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a form which has an input called "net worth" and I have an embedded widget below this input which you can choose your currency and insert your budget and it would convert it to your desired currency. it looks like this:

[image: The widget box]

You can check online the widget [here](https://currencyrate.today/converter-widget).

So I want whenever the result changes (**onChange**) my input field value changes too. The result is in the **span** with *#result-fit* ID and my **input** box is *#netWorthValue* ,
I have searched a lot and try some best practice but still, I can not figure it out. The most relevent question in Stackoverflow was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649003/value-from-span-to-input) question but it couldn't help me unfortunately, I have tested this code and it didn't retrieve the value from span (maybe because it is inside an embedded form?)

```js
var value = $("#result-fit").text();
var lower = $("#netWorthValue").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
var value = $("#result-fit").text();
var lower = $("#netWorthValue").val(value);
alert(lower.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <p>Your personal net worth</p>


  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Amount in CDN (Canadian dollar):</label> <input type="number" class="form-control" name="netWorth" title="networth" id="netWorthValue">




    <!-- START CODE Attention! Do not modify this code; -->
    <script>
      var fm = "EUR";
      var to = "CAD";
      var tz = "timezone";
      var sz = "1x1";
      var lg = "en";
      var st = "info";
      var lr = "0";
      var rd = "0";
    </script>
    <a href="https://currencyrate.today/converter-widget" title="Currency Converter">
      <script src="//currencyrate.today/converter"></script>
    </a>
 
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to put the JavaScript in an event handler that runs when the user does something.

Comment: I don't see `id="result-fit"` anywhere in the HTML.

Comment: Because it loads with Widget and I have try event handler like this examples https://jsfiddle.net/6khr8e2b/
https://jsfiddle.net/justinmichaels/Wnyhg/1/
And still nothing, I have some doubt that it may be the problem of the widget loading

Comment: Put all the relevant code in the question, we shouldn't have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Doesn't the widget do this automatically? Why do you need to listen for the change yourself?

Comment: Are you trying to detect when the result in the widget changes? There's no `change` event for spans, only for inputs. The widget may provide its own event that you can listen for.

Comment: Yes you are right but I can just inspect this box, the code won't show up in the main HTML and with embedded JS file it loads a whole another large HTML file which I can not copy it here and because of that I have attached the widget in the snippet so you can inspect. but the important part is the box which is called result-fit ID

Comment: What i want: onChange span, my value copy to another input file outside the widget so I can send it with my form

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation for the widget. The source code is minified, so it's difficult to read. I didn't see anything that looked like an event trigger, so I think you'll need to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: You could also just use `setInterval` to run something every second that copies the span to the input. Or give the user a button they can click to copy it.

Comment: I didn't know that there is no onChange event for the span, so I appreciate your offer and I will read the MutationObserver documents, I may find a better way for it, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Listen for changes to the input and write to the '#result-fit' span.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result-fit").on("change", function(e){
       $("#netWorthValue").text($(this).val());    
    })
})
```

Comment: He wants to go the other way. When `#result-fit` changes, he wants to copy it to `#netWorthValue`.